# check if user has module edit permission when page is not in edit mode

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am developing a module for DNN 7.1+ and I need to display / hide a link in the module based on if the user has edit permission for that module.  I want this to happen regardless of whether or not the page is in edit mode.

Currently I have the following code in the view.ascx of the custom module page load event:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        ''other code goes here.......
        If IsEditable = True Then
            AdminEdit.Visible = True
        Else
            AdminEdit.Visible = False
        End If
    Catch exc As Exception
        Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(Me, exc)
    End Try

End Sub
```

**AdminEdit** is the ID of the  element I want to hide.  This code works when the page is in edit mode, but I want this  to always be visible, regardless of edit mode, if the user has edit permission for that module.

Right now the IsEditbale returns false if page is not in edit mode.

**QUESTION:** How can I check the user permission without the page being in edit mode?

EDIT: I would also be happy with checking against the user's edit permission for the page containing the module

### SOLUTION:

Here is what I ended up with thanks to bdukes:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try

            ''display template selector if user has edit rights over module
            If DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.ModulePermissionController.CanEditModuleContent(Me.ModuleConfiguration) Then
                AdminEdit.Visible = True
            Else
                AdminEdit.Visible = False
            End If
        Catch exc As Exception
            Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(Me, exc)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All that `IsEditable` does is tell you if you're in edit mode.  To check permissions, use `DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.ModulePermissionController.CanEditModuleContent(modInfo)`.

Checking the permissions of users other than the current user is quite a bit messier and more fragile.  At a basic level, you can call [`PortalSecurity.IsInRoles`](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/dnn-api/?topic=html/cfb1f17a-d031-5e4c-c2e0-84fb2c33958c.htm) and follow the example at [`PermissionProvider`](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/eff4ec346909b1d186c04a5168110e672b845a8b/DNN%20Platform/Library/Security/Permissions/PermissionProvider.cs#L752-L755) to pass in `modInfo.ModulePermissions.ToString("EDIT")`.  However, `"EDIT"` here is a value defined in the permission provider, and Evoq uses a different permission provider (in order to provide more granular permissions), so it's possible that different environment may have different permissions you want to check.

Comment: Thanks, i posted my code that ended up with, would you mind checking it to see if its what you meant.  Because this code happens inside the module in question, is there a shorter way of getting the module info or do I really need to declare a module controller and then the module info separate like I have in my solution?

Comment: You should be able to pass `Me.ModuleConfiguration`

Comment: what if we need to check Permission for a user other than current user?

Comment: @Ehsan, I've edited my answer to address your question